# Get json data from url

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have following part of code which works fine. Now I want to get my "list" from specific url which response with json data.

```
(function() {
  var app, list;

  list = [
      {
        'name': 'Foo',
        'title': 'Designer'
      },{
        'name': 'Bar',
        'title': 'Designer'
      }
    ];
```

simple `list = $http.get('/data_url/').success(function(data));` do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$http.get` function does not return the data. You can handle with the response data in the success callback.

You have to set the data like this:

```
$http.get('/data_url/').then(function(data){
    list = data;
});
```

Comment: use the `then` method instead of the `success` method

Comment: it's the same, no result. It seems that request is not sent at all. I'm use Angular 1.3.2

Comment: please check at the developer tools of your browser if the request will be sent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102173/discussion-between-fiete-and-goran).

Comment: Just to let you know. I'm change line to this ` $http.get('/data_url/').then(function(response){$scope.list = response.data}); ` and it works fine now. Thank you very much.